# Why die with connect_error() is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, mysqli

Main question:

I'm trying to print error on web page if the connection to MySQL server is not made. For this, I written a wrong database name `$this->dbname = 'dbinds';` (actual is **dbind**). But the **die** statement is not executing. When I open the page, it simply doesn't load. It shows error: **The localhost page isn’t working.** 
Am I doing something wrong?

Another question:
I've commented the exception handling code block. Now when I use it, it works fine. The exception is thrown if there's some mistake. But if you see, I've written the **2nd exception throw code block** below `$this->abc=$this->con->prepare();` statement. But it doesn't work if I write this below `$this->abc->execute();`

Is there any way to throw exceptions for each statement? (Like, prepare, bind and execute).

Here's my code:

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    public $abc;
    public $con;
    public function __construct()
    {
       // ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $this->servername = 'localhost';
        $this->username = 'root';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->dbname = 'dbinds';
        $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname);
        if($this->con->connect_error){
            die("Something: ".connect_error());
        }
        /*if(!$this->con) {
           throw new Exception("Connection can't be made");
        }*/
        return $this->con;
    }

    public function insert_data($emp_name, $emp_dept, $emp_salary)
    {
        $this->abc=$this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(name, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        //FOLLOWING IF BLOCK
        /*if(!$this->abc) {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't insert data");
        }*/
        $this->abc->bind_param("ssi", $emp_name, $emp_dept, $emp_salary);
        $this->abc->execute();

    }
}
?>
<?php
$conobj=new Database();
$query=$conobj->insert_data("vvsdf", "vsomeone", 3445);
/*try{
    $conobj=new Database();
    $query=$conobj->insert_data("vvsdf", "vsomeone", 3445);

} catch (Exception $e ) {
    //echo "Service unavailable";
    echo "message: " . $e->getMessage();   // not in live code obviously...
   // echo $e;
    exit;
}*/
?>
```

Comment: I did the same. But it's not working.

Comment: Yes this would work I know. Could you say something about 2nd question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide whether you use procedular or [object oriented version of mysqli.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

However, still you can change your if condtion to:

```
if (!$this->con) {
   die(mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

it should work. You can also see [the example on manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: `connect_error()` didn't echo because I've written procedural function for connect?

Comment: Further, it works but after changing the condition in if statement to yours. Why is that?

Comment: because I check if mysqli_connect returns connection object and if not then it means there's an error so I display it.